# Blur contenteditable div while keeping the current selection?

Tags: jquery, formatting, highlight, contenteditable

Currently, the code for the popup box is done, as well as the code for the contenteditable div. But I'm having quite a hard time trying to figure out a way to lose focus of the contenteditable div while keeping the selected range and acting on it. Basically here's the result of the current code:

1. User inputs text into contenteditable div
2. User highlights text from contenteditable div
3. Popup box with formatting icons slides up on to the position of the current selection
4. If you do it correctly, when holding down or dragging on the formatting bar or its buttons, the contenteditable div in the back will highlight text as if the popup box with formatting wasn't there. Almost as if, the click events on the formatting buttons themselves go right through

This is very hard to explain as you can probably tell. I'll provide a further example. [This is how I want it to be.](https://i.gyazo.com/9ee2ce6359ec84d9a41977cf19840e11.gif) [This is how it is currently.](https://gyazo.com/e1877b0563c62df9bb14e2b6f26cd753) Notice how in the second link, when I click and drag on the bold button, the text in the back gets highlighted, as opposed to in the first link, where the original highlighted text stays highlighted and nothing else happens. Please, if anyone can help me that would be amazing. I'm so frustrated, nothing has worked so far.